# My recursive file search dont work properly

Tags: php, function, recursion

I have a code, which is meant for searching a specified string in all files and check subdirectorys too. At the end i return an array, which contains the filename and the line numbers. Anyways i only get an array filled with the last checked folder.

```
function scan2($dir,$pre,$counter,$arr) {

include("config.php");  //CONTAINS AN ARRAY OF PATHS WHICH CAN BE SKIPPED
$mergedArray['gesamt'] = 0;

if($counter > 0)
{
    $mergedArray['gesamt'] = $counter; //COUNTS THE TOTAL AMOUNT OF ENTRYS
}



$pre.= "-";
$dh = opendir($dir);

while($file = readdir($dh)) 
{
if($file != "." && $file != "..") 
{
  if(is_dir($dir."/".$file) && !in_array("$dir/$file",$pfade)) //IF IS DIRECTORY
  {
    scan2($dir.'/'.$file,$pre,$counter,$arr);
  }
  else // IF IS FILE
  {
    $handle = fopen($dir.'/'.$file, "r");               

    $string = "";
    $raw = "";
    $count = 0;
    $counter = $counter;
    $info = pathinfo($dir."/".$file);
    if($info["extension"] == "php" || $info["extension"] == "js" || $info["extension"] == "html" || $info["extension"] == "xml")
    {
        while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false)
        {

            $count++;
            if(strpos($line,$_GET['suche']) == true)
            {
                $string .= $count.',';
                $counter++;
            }

            $raw = substr($string, 0, -1);

        }
        $pfad = $dir.'/'.$file;
        echo $pfad.' -- '.$raw.'<hr>';
        if(strlen($raw) > 0) {
            $mergedArray['eintraege'][$pfad] = $raw;
        }
        fclose($handle);
    }
  }
}
}
array_push($arr, $mergedArray);
closedir($dh);
return $mergedArray;
}


// OUTSIDE THE FUNCTION
$arr = Array();
$tt = scan2("C:/xampp1/htdocs_micha","", 0, $arr);
echo'<pre>';
print_r($tt);
echo'</pre>';
```

I really hope you guys understand my question and can help me.

Best regards: me

Comment: the config.php just looks like:
$pfade[0] = 'C:/xampp/htdocs_1/moreFiles/';
$pfade[1] = 'C:/xampp/htdocs_2/';

Comment: Do not add codes in comments. __EDIT__ your question.

Comment: Looks like you try to reinvent the `grep` utility? Why not use that instead?